# Ubuntu SDK emulator starts up but the Devices tab says "The device is currently booting..."

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, scopes

I'm trying to setup an Ubuntu emulated device with a click package. But even after the emulator starts up the devices tab show that the device is booting. Pressing the refresh button does not help either and the loading continues.

[image: Screenshot of SDK and Emulator]

This makes it impossible to create Kits as the SDK thinks that the application is still booting.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is that you have to enable the developer mode on the emulator by hand.
Navigate to System Settings > About this phone > Developer mode and enable the developer mode.

Afterwards the IDE should be able to connect to the emulator.